# How can I emulate PHP's crazy global thing?

Tags: php, global-variables

If I have a file `a.php` **which I can't edit.**

```
<?php
$a = 1;
function a() {
  global $a;
  echo $a;
}  
a();
```

then running `php a.php` prints `1` nicely. But if I have `b.php`:

```
<?php
function b() {
  include "a.php";
}
b();
```

Then running `php b.php` doesn't print anything.

What can I type before the `include "a.php"` to make it behave the same without editing `a.php`?

(Obviously other than defining `$a`. In my real-world example it has to work for a complicated `a.php`).

Comment: Well, you ARE trying to define a global variable inside a function and then wondering how come it doesn't work. :)

Comment: While this can be solved with more "global", I'd strongly recommend to refactor the code in `a.php` and replace globals for example with function parameters.

Comment: try changing the `a()` to `a($input = $a)`

Comment: Added clarification, feel free to roll back if you don't like it

Comment: For context, `a.php` is MediaWiki.

Comment: It seems the problem is with including `a.php` inside a function. Then, why not just include `a.php` outside any function?

Comment: @clapas I'm trying to write a unit test, and the framework needs all tests to be defined in functions named `testSomething`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `a.php` is some legacy or 3rd party script that you have to wrap in your own application. I had a similar problem once and the solution was not pretty. First, you will **have to** find out, what global variables exist (`grep global` or similar helps).

This is the relevant part of my "Script Adapter" class:

```
private function _includeScript($file, $globals)
{
    foreach ($globals as $global) {
        global $$global;
    }

    ob_start();
    require $file;
    $this->_response->setBody(ob_get_clean());
}
```

As you see, I had to catch the output too. The class also emulates `$_GET` and catches `header` calls to assign everything to a `Response` object, but for your case only this method is important. It gets called with the file name and an array of global variable **names** as parameters:

```
_includeScript('a.php', array('a'));
```

Comment: My list of globals is now 13,105 characters long, but it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a global into your new function:

```
function b() {
  global $a;

  include "a.php";
}
```

At the moment I wonder if PHP is treating `$a` as local to your `b()` function.

Addendum: in response to your comment, it seems that you need to grab arbitrary variables that your include has created locally in your function, and remake them as global. This works for me on 5.3.20 on OSX 10.6.8:

```
function b() {
    include 'a.php';

    // Move variables into global space
    foreach (get_defined_vars() as $name => $value) {
        global $$name;
        // global wipes the value, so just reset it
        $$name = $value;
        echo "Declared $name as global\n";
    }
}

b();
// Your global vars should be available here
```

Obviously you can remove the `echo` once you're happy it works.

Comment: I don't know what variables need to be defined. `a.php` is really complicated

Comment: That's *atrocious,* but very smart and will do the job. :) +1

Comment: Heh, I'm in a hacky mood today!

Comment: The `echo $a` is actually in `a.php` and was just illustrative.

Comment: This will not work because a.php relies on the variables being global, which they are not at the time of execution.

Comment: @Paul: ah, I see what you mean - I think I've misunderstood your problem. You don't want global vars from your `include` to made available after it runs, you want the include to generate HTML output of some kind. Perhaps that requires global variables defined elsewhere? I am not familiar with MediaWiki.

Comment: Hmm, the only thing I can think of right now is to do `print_r(get_defined_vars())` on a sample run after the `include` to see what variables are generated, and then manually add a `global` for each one prior to the `include`.

Comment: Just a thought, is there a `require_once` or `include_once` inside MediaWiki for its initialisation process? If so, you could call that manually, run my globalisation code, then do your include - MediaWiki (hopefully) won't then re-include the already included file.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a function inside a function? Yuck. But I guess you have a real-world situation that doesn't allow any other way. But for the record, this is REALLY BAD PRACTICE

Adding `global $a` to `b()` should work.

```
function b() {
  global $a;
  include "a.php";
}
```

> I don't know what variables need to be defined. a.php is really complicated

Then the only way I can think of is not using a function in b.php, so you're in the global scope when including a.php. I can see no other way.

Comment: I don't know what variables need to be defined. `a.php` is really complicated

Comment: @Paul then the only way that comes to mind is not using a function in b.php. I can see no other way